# password_verify never returning true

Tags: php, hash

so Im trying to set up a very simple account system. Part of that is that passwords are encrypted on registering via password_hash. The username and the hashed password gets stored in my database 'users'. When I try to login the password_verify never returns true even though Im 100% certain I used the right password. 
Here is my login.php:

```
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
 header("location: welcome.php");
 exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

 // Check if username is empty
 if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
     $username_err = "Please enter username.";
 } else{
     $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
 }

 // Check if password is empty
 if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
     $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
 } else{
     $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
 }

 // Validate credentials
 if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
     // Prepare a select statement
     $sql = "SELECT idkunde, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

     if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
         // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

         // Set parameters
         $param_username = $username;

         // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
         if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
             // Store result
             mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

             // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
             if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                 // Bind result variables
                 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);

                 if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                     echo $hashed_password;
                     if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){

                         // Password is correct, so start a new session
                         session_start();

                         // Store data in session variables
                         $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                         $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

                         // Redirect user to welcome page
                         header("location: welcome.php");
                     } else{
                         // Display an error message if password is not valid
                         $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                     }
                 }
             } else{
                 // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                 $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
             }
         } else{
             echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
         }
     }

     // Close statement
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 }

 // Close connection
 mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
 <style type="text/css">
     body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
     .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <h2>Login</h2>
 <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
 <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
     <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
         <label>Username</label>
         <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
         <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
         <label>Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
         <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
     </div>
     <p>Don't have an account? <a href="registration.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont think my registration is at fault here because It stores everything as expected. If you want to check for yourself here is my registration.php

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT idkunde FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
        </div>
        <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The config.php just sets up a connection to the database 'ebanking'

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'ebanking');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Appreciate any help!

EDIT

So I found the error. I accidently set the maximum length of my password column to 24. Setting it to 255 resolved the issue.

Comment: You have a `header()` without `exit()`, best set `exit()`(at `// Redirect to login page` and at `// Redirect user to welcome page`). What debugging have you done?

Comment: I've checked the returns of my Select statement which seems fine. Also checked both the password and the hashed_password which are used in the password_verify. Both are what I expected them to be. So couldnt really make out the error.